# OpenCV - Remove noise in image using Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to create an OCR application. I need to locate the text using contours. However, my image has a lot of noise and I was wondering if there is a way to remove it.

My current code:

```
// Input image already converted to a matrix
Imgproc.cvtColor(matrixImage, matrixImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

// Gaussian blur
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(matrixImage, matrixImage, new Size(7,7), 0);

Imgproc.threshold(matrixImage, matrixImage, 125, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

// This is my current approach for removing noise. However, there is still 
// a lot of random areas that can be removed.

// Remove specs from image
Mat morphingMatrix = Mat.ones(3,3, CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.morphologyEx(matrixImage, matrixImage, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, morphingMatrix);

// Image denoising
Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(matrixImage, matrixImage);
```

My input image. I allow users to manually mark the corners so the transformed image below only applies the transformation to the middle white piece of paper.

[image: input image]

[image: image after transformation]

Comment: How did your image look after transforming? Can u upload that image?

Comment: The second image is the transformed image

Comment: I understand, but it is in black/white (binary). I would like the transformed image in original color space (RGB)

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for your problem. However, it does not involve removal of noise in this case.

**Step 1:**

I have obtained my own transformed image from the original image uploaded by you:

[image]

I presume you know how to perform transformations on images as stated in your question. Nevertheless to learn more about them visit [THIS](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/). To learn about homographic proJections visit [THIS SITE](http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/).

I obtained the gray scale of this image:

[image]

**Step 2:**

To this image I performed adaptive threshold using *Gaussian filter*:

[image]

**Step 3:**

This step involves a couple of morphological operations:

Firstly, to remove the unwanted spots in the image, I used morphological ***closing*** operation:

[image]

Secondly, I used morphological ***dilation*** operation (which you may not need unless you want to highlight your text):

[image]